# How can you order search results on a custom field with SobiPro?

Tags: joomla3.0, sobipro

I have pored over the SobiPro forum for hours and find tons of people with the same question as this, but no actual, working answers to it so I'm hoping I have more success here.

I want my SobiPro search results to be sorted by the start date (a custom field) for each event so in General Configuration/Template//Entry Settings I have my vCard Settings/Order By set to "Start Date Ascending" but after clicking on Search the results consistently come out in some other order (not sure what it's ordering it on). I'm using myjoom Radius Search to provide the radius search functionality, idk if that interferes with anything.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong and, more importantly, how to just get my output sorted by Start Date field?

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, did you found a solution to this problem? If so I ask you to kindly post a reply because I also have this need. Thank you :)

Comment: Somewhat - I couldn;t get anything useful from SobiPro to set a preference or something but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/32902445/1745001 for how to edit the XSL to do this. I still have the problem though that although I can now get the search results sorted correctly on each page of output, the actual pages are in reverse order when the search results span pages! If you come up with a fix for that or a better approach please do share....!